# Algorithm to detect node failure in a distributed system

Tags: algorithm, distributed-computing, distributed-system

I was going through this [lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MnYlwjuGcg8&list=PLOE1GTZ5ouRPbpTnrZ3Wqjamfwn_Q5Y9A&index=6) on YouTube.

Here the lecturer describes an algorithm to detect node failure in a distributed system.

The snapshot where he describes the algorithm is as follows.
[image: SNAPSHOT]

I am not clear with the explanation he gives for choosing floor(N/2) as the threshold. The lecturer says that if we take a number less than floor(N/2) we might not be able to differentiate between a scenario where a node is part of a smaller partition and the rest of the nodes have failed, and the node is part of a smaller partition which has been cut off from the rest of the nodes, which are communicating fine with each other.
During the lecture, he makes the assumption that the graph he is talking about is connected, ie every pair of nodes has a path or a way to reach each other.

How is the threshold chosen ? I am not very clear with that. I could've done my research but I just couldn't figure out *what* to type in Google for this algorithm

Comment: Google:    detecting node failure distributed "floor(n/2)".

Comment: I assume the goal is to make sure that only one group of connected nodes continues to run. So each node must verify that it's part of a group that contains more than half the total nodes. If a node is in a group that contains exactly half of the total nodes, then there could be another group that also contains exactly half, and you'd have two groups still running.